# does Celery automatically create an EC2 Machine?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, celery, django-celery

I've been playing with django and celery on EC2. Everything was fine.
Lately I noticed that I've been charged of an additional machine that I didn't know to have.

checking I've a machine in Irland (my main machine is located in US) that is called 
`celery-test-env-3`

every time I terminate it, it's automatically recreated.

- I stopped celery with (`sudo service celeryd stop`)
- I deactivated all the aws keys.
- I even stop the US machine.

nothing changes: the celery-test machine it's recreated every time I terminate one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, celery doesn't do that. Check your EC2 config, maybe it respawns terminated instances.